# Auto inject properties in Angular component to reduce boilerplate code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

We are developing a large AngularJS (1.5) application which consists of a large number of constants that almost every Angular components' templates would use.  Currently, we resort to manually assign those constants to every component's controller, but we would like to see if there are ways to simplify this.

Here is our current implementation

```js
import TranslationKeys from '../keys/translationkeys';
import ApplicationConstants from '../constants/applicationconstants';

module.component('humbleComponent', {
    bindings: {},
    controller: () => {
        this.TranslationKeys = TranslationKeys;
        this.ApplicationConstants = ApplicationConstants;
    }
    template: '<div>{{ $ctrl.TranslationKeys.HELLO | translate }}</div>'
});
```

Our ideal outcome would be:

1. Eliminate repeat assignment of `TranslationKeys` and `ApplicationConstants`
2. Ideally, accessing those constants in the template would not even need to reference `$ctrl`.  Such as

```js
import TranslationKeys from '../keys/translationkeys';
import ApplicationConstants from '../constants/applicationconstants';

module.component('humbleComponent', {
    bindings: {},
    controller: () => {
        //Look mom, no need to repeated keys/constants assignments here
    }
    template: '<div>{{ TranslationKeys.HELLO | translate }} <!-- No need to use $ctrl when accessing TranslationKeys--> </div>'
});
```

Just wondering what are the ways to achieve the goals above.

Comment: you can put all constants in $rootScope

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, that is an interesting idea, but it would require the template to reference those as `$root.TranslationKeys`, it would be nice not to expose them this way.

Comment: no, you can address it directly, same as for vars in $scope: http://plnkr.co/edit/RNcxlz970RMuzY5aer4R?p=preview. Actually this is nearly only way that meets your goals, another is - decorate angular $interpolate/$compile services... and this should be very tricky.